# Show method from resource controller returns null

Tags: forms, laravel, variables, controller, resources

I'm having trouble with learning laravel and decided to ask my question here since I can't find an answer via Google etc.

I am trying to return a client from the database via Id, maybe later via name.

This is my form:

```
<<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Klant invoeren</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}">
</head>
<body>

<p><<form action="{{route('client/'.$client->id.'/show/')}}"
      method="get">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="price">Achternaam:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id">
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-        
left:38px">Zoek klant</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Which redirects to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Klant invoeren</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h2>Voer een klant in</h2><br  />
    <h1>Showing {{ var_dump($client) }}</h1>


    </div>
</body>
</html>`
```

And this is the show method from the Clientcontroller:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $client = Client::find($id);
    return view('clients.show', compact('client'));
}
```

This is the route I'm using:

```
Route::get('client/{id}/show','ClientController@show');
```

Can someone spot my mistake, because I can't after messing with this the last few hours.

EDIT: updated code and added the route, now getting the error that the client variable isn't defined in the

Answer (score 0):

You must echo the client id in the form action. So, remove the **inverted comma** from $client->id. Use the following code :

```
<form action="{{action('ClientController@show', $client->id)}}"             
method="get">
```

Additionally, remove **backtick** from the code. Use the following code :

```
public function show($id)
{
    $client = Client::find($id);
    return view('clients.show', compact('client')); 
}
```

Comment: If i do it like this I get the error that $client from $client-id is undefined :/

Comment: I am just finding an error in your code. I don't know which method is used to display the view having above form.

Comment: Well I was using return View::make('clients.show')
        ->with('client', $client);
But either one works

Answer (score 0):

In your routes/web.php

```
       Route::get('client/{id}/show','ClientController@show');
```

In your form:

```
       <form action="{{URL::to('client/'.$client->id.'/show/')}}"
```

method="get">

In your controller:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $client = Client::find($id);
    return view('clients.show', compact('client')); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Luciano. I copied your code but I am still getting the undefined variable $client error in my view

Comment: Here you go: 
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Undefined variable: client (View: /var/www/html/LaravelProjects/GroepOef1/resources/views/clients/showClient.blade.php)

Comment: you are returning the wrong view, change this: public function show($id)
{
    $client = Client::find($id);
    return view('clients.showClient', compact('client')); 
}

Comment: I did that but I am still getting the same error. The form is where the variable is undefined

Comment: edit your question posting your view, controller and routes/web.php

Answer (score 0):

In your Client Controller make sure you use the Model that you are referencing to

Assuming App\Client.php Change it to App\User.php if you are referring to user

ClientController

```
use App\Client;

public function show($id)
{
    $client = Client::find($id);
    return view('clients.show', compact('client')); 
}
```

Now you can fetch the client model with $client For example $client->id

Make sure you pass the {id} parameter in the route

Comment: That still doesn't change anything unfortunately :/